# Motherboard issues for custom machine learning computer

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, processor, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a custom machine with the following specs:

- MSI Z270 SLI Plus motherboard
- NVIDIA 1080-Ti GTX GPU
- Intel i7-7700 CPU
- 4 x 16GB Kingston HyperX RAM cards
- Ubuntu 16.04 OS

I haven't had great luck with this MSI MoBo and am considering buying another board. Any recommendations from fellow data science / crypto nerds out there? I hate calling support when I'm having an issue and being told "technically we only support Windows..."

Comment: I'm not going to flag it, but I think you should edit your question to orient itself better towards Hardware Recommendations rather than support. I'm going to answer it anyways (in a bit!) but in the future, purely "support" questions are better on sites like superuser.com

Comment: You seem to have two separate issues here as well: one is your computer not posting, the other is your ML issue. Let's separate that out into different questions. You also mention crypto: Are you mining on this rig as well? If so, are you planning to move to multiple cards? What are you mining?

Comment: Ignoring that though, a couple things: Why use a Z series board with a locked CPU? What are you doing that's actually going to be incurring significant overhead on your GPU (read: why not just use your GPU for the displays as well?) I don't understand where "I cannot setup CUDA because the GPU is powering the graphics." is coming from. What ML library are you using? CNTK, TensorFlow, Theasno?

Comment: Regarding the lack of POST: Reset CMOS, try switching BIOSs, reseat the CPU checking for any damage, and if all else fails, take it to someone else to test it/RMA.

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks for not flagging and responding. Will edit the question to focus purely on hardware recommendations. To answer your other questions related to support: I'm just interested in dabbling with crypto, perhaps mining a few alt currencies (e.g. monero, zcash). My main interest is in using CUDA for conv neural nets. To your question "Why use a Z series board..." I don't even know what that means. I suppose that's where the hardware recommendation comes in. What other boards should I be thinking about?

Comment: @JMY1000 Re "I cannot setup CUDA..." several online guides I consulted for setting up CUDA on Ubuntu said that you need to run the graphics off of the CPU, not the GPU, at least when installing the drivers. Indeed, when I attempted to setup CUDA I ran into some errors (I wish I could be more specific. Didn't save the terminal output). Looking at this post -- https://medium.com/@samir_moussa/battling-through-an-nvidia-gpu-setup-in-the-name-of-machine-learning-c7ebd5b36f87 -- it seems that this is probably related to my having to use nouveau.modset=0 from the GRUB.

Comment: Long story short, I skipped to playing around with the hardware before exhausting all my software options and am now paying the price for it. Will edit my question to solicit a solid hardware recommendation in the event that I've accidentally torched my motherboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70912/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-aaron).

Comment: @JMY1000 Quick update: https://medium.com/@aaronpolhamus/building-a-centos-7-machine-learning-station-with-nvidia-cuda-integration-everything-i-learned-17aed82ab3ce. Thanks for all the help! It seems that it was alternating my connector cables between the integrated and GPU ports that scrambled the board.

Comment: Interesting post, but it's a bit outside the strictly hardware recs space. That said: I still don't know why you had issues with Ubuntu. CUDA has worked fine for me (though admittedly I was using it headlessly rather than with Unity, though if you like GNOME, there's nothing preventing you from using it on Ubuntu–they're actually switching the default back soon.) Server compute can also be much cheaper than you posted using things like Reserve Instances on EC2, but building your own is almost always bound to be cheaper... if you pick the right hardware. On that note...

Comment: 1. You spent what I'd consider to be a lot of money on a case, but if you like it, no harm. 2. You bought a relatively weak cooler for a relatively high price that won't allow you to reach your full potential with your CPU. 3. You spent a lot of money on memory. 4. You bought a 7700K, but AFAIK neither overclocked nor made particularly good use of hyperthreading. 5. Bought an expensive motherboard.

Comment: With the $2200, you could've bought a used Dell T5500 [~$200](https://us.bidvoy.net/dell_t5500/179), 4x8GB DDR3 [~$100](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR1.TRC0.A0.H0.X4x8gb+ddr3+ec.TRS0&_nkw=4x8gb+ddr3+ecc&_sacat=0), a new PSU for around $100, and ~4 GTX 980Tis at [$400 each](https://us.bidvoy.net/980ti/27386/6m) with a 10% "not-US" premium to spare.

Comment: The problem with your build wasn't compatibility or putting it together for the most part (those are technical issues that you can overcome), but **realizing what you needed.** *That's* what hardware recs is for, and it's quite probable that a better build could've been had for less while saving your friend some time and you some cash. Your original post is a classic example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "Making sure you have all the key ingredients" is easy–we have PCPartPicker for that. What's hard is finding the ingredients that make the best recipe. Throwing more money at the problem with an i9 doesn't do anything to help if you need more GPU power.

Comment: And if you still need help with those Wi-Fi drivers, https://superuser.com/ should be a good spot (and one that you're familiar with, too!)

Comment: @JMY1000 Now I know, thanks for all the follow-ups, man.

Comment: @JMY1000 The 4x GTX 980 Tis is an interesting idea. Good for hyper-parameter searching across light-weight conv net training runs. For single heavy training jobs I'm not sure that that would provide an advantage.